# How is it possible to be the 4979th user to get a bronze tag in Java, but rank 8260?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, data-explorer

When I was awarded Bronze tag in Java my number was 4979. But the rank as shown [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527106/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-what-percentage-you-are-in-a-particular-tag?tagname=java&UserId=1475228) is 8260?

How is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tag badges have requirements for score *and* number of answers, whereas that ranking is purely based on score only. There are plenty of users who have a higher score than you in the tag but have not posted enough answers in it to qualify for the badge.

For example, I have a score of 36 in the Java tag (more than a third of the progress for the score requirement), but have only posted two answers in that tag (a mere tenth of the requirement). Sometimes simple or common answers in a popular language attract a high number of votes that skew one part of the badge way out of proportion to the other.

Your query also includes questions, which do not contribute to tag badges at all. So if a user only ever asks questions in that tag, they could get a score higher than you with zero progress towards the badge.